# jQuery Mobile: UI restyling after AJAX content loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I need to apply JQM to some markup loaded via AJAX. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done. Every jQM element has its own refresh method used for restyling.

For example:

- Listview has a:

  ```
  $('#listviewID').listview('refresh');
  ```

Hers's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AzXdT/. This is a listview dynamically generated from XML data.

- Button elements have a:

  ```
  $('#buttonID').button('refresh');
  ```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/K8nMX/

- Slider has a:

  ```
  $('#sliderID').slider('refresh')
  ```
- Selectmenu has a:

  ```
  $('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
  ```

By now you can see a pattern here. To refresh always use a component name as s function with 'refresh' parameter.

In case you are doing a whole page restyle you should use this [method](http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html).

Happy X-Mas to you to m8. :)

Comment: Thanks M8, your answer shed light upon my problem. ;)